# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key storyboardName

Tags: ios, storyboard, nsunknownkeyexception

My app crashes on launch with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key storyboardName.'

Comment: checkout your view controller outlet

Comment: Thankx i will check it...:)

Answer (score 2):

This normally happens when you previously had an `IBOutlet` connection from your storyboard scene to it's corresponding `viewController` and at some point you removed the outlet from the scene or `viewController` and did not remove the connection. Hence the error.

Either reconnect it or remove the connection completely (in code and on the storyboard )

Comment: Thankxx i will check it...